# Ruby encryption/decryption with secure password

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, encryption

I want to connect two ruby interfaces. I want to pass key and secret from interface 1 to interface 2 in encrypted form and user in interface 2 can decrypt the key and secret if he has a specific password. Which is the best way to implement it?

Comment: Do you mean key and secret message? Do you want to use the key to encrypt the message? "secret" usually has a different meaning in crypto.

Answer (score 0):

Use PBKDF2 to generate a key from a salt and the password. You can use this key to perform key wrapping (encryption) over a randomized key you want to agree on. You could simply use AES in ECB mode of operation if you only encrypt a randomized key value.

If you also need to encrypt a message then take the key and use an authenticated mode of encryption like GCM and use that to encrypt. If that's not available then use CBC and HMAC, but don't forget to include the IV vector in the HMAC calculation over the ciphertext. Sending non-authenticated ciphertext over the internet is not likely to be secure.

If available you could also use TLS with PSK authentication. That would almost certainly provide better protection than some kind of proprietary scheme such as the one above.

Comment: @Maarteen- Is it possible to decrypt the encrypted password?

Comment: Nope, that should not be possible if not strictly required. Password decryption does not seem implied by your question.

Comment: what about whatsapp messages? they are encrypted and decrypted, so they are not secure ?

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of Options available, I liked Gibberish

1. [Gibberish](https://github.com/mdp/gibberish)
2. [gpgme](https://github.com/ueno/ruby-gpgme)
3. [encrypted strings](https://github.com/pluginaweek/encrypted_strings)

Comment: Just pointing to some random websites should not be considered an answer, especially if these websites do not provide a full resolution to the question and are easily abused. The author of "encrypted strings" thinks hashing is encryption; you cannot get much worse than that. Gibberish feels flaky too, and does not authenticate ciphertext by default. At least GPGME uses a standard container format.